# What happens to degeneration as a compact star cools down?

Tags: astrophysics

Compact stellar objects are substained by degeneration of electron (white dwarfs) or neutron (neutron star).

I wonder what happens to this degenerate matter as the star cools down?

Comment: When there is no further degeneration possible, the star cools down. (not the other way around)

Comment: @JMLCarter I have clarified my question.

Comment: Well in theory it could go to the next level (especially as they tend to stop rotating with age).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_star, or they could just reach a steady state.